# Can you run multiple tests in one browser context Playwright Javascript?

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, playwright

Is it possible to run multiple tests in one browser window for playwright/test?

currently it will hit browser.close(); after every test even though they are testing on the same page which puts a lot of extra time on the tests.

```
test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
});

test('nav test', async ({ page }) => {    
  const name = await page.innerText('.navbar__title');  
  expect(name).toBe('Playwright');
});

test('header test', async ({ page }) => {   
  const name = await page.innerText('.navbar__header');  
  expect(name).toBe('Playwright');
});
```

Answer (score 24):

When you create a tests like this  `test('header test', async ({page}) => {`  you're specifying `page` and telling it to create a new page context.

Remove the `page` from the test - and share the one you create from your `.beforeAll`

Try this:

```py
test.describe('1 page multiple tests', () => {
    let page;
    test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
        const context = await browser.newContext();
        page = await context.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://example.com');
    });

    test.afterAll(async ({ browser }) => {
        browser.close;
    });

    test('nav test', async () => {
        const name = await page.innerText('h1');
        expect(name).toContain('Example');
    });

    test('header test', async () => {
        const name = await page.innerText('h1');
        expect(name).toContain('Domain');
    });
});
```

Run it like this :

```
npx playwright test .\StackTests_SinglePage.spec.ts --headed
```

*(you can see the name of my file in there)*

You might need to toggle it down to 1 worker if it tries to parallel run your test.

For me, that code opens 1 borwser, 1 page, passes both tests the closes out.
[image]

Comment: If you are using playwright.config.ts "https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#emulation" Does this work passing the newContext to test on different browsers?

Comment: The same code above works fine cross browser.  Playwright isolates all these fixtures by design. That's why sharing the page in the describe keeps the same context. If you have a more detailed question around your configuration you might want to create a new question. It's a different one than you've asked here and it means other people can support you ... if the above answers what you asked it's good to mark it as the right answer so others searching around the same problem can learn :-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try wrapping the tests in a describe block? So they are treated as a group and not as an individual tests.

```js
test.describe('two tests for same page', () => {
   test('nav test', async ({ page }) => {    
     const name = await page.innerText('.navbar__title');  
     expect(name).toBe('Playwright');
   });

   test('header test', async ({ page }) => {   
    const name = await page.innerText('.navbar__header');  
    expect(name).toBe('Playwright');
  });
});
```

Comment: Wrapping still seems to open a new browser each time, Id like to keep it open and use it then call a browser close in test.afterAll